# Replacing the original pixel values with the predicted values by model: it returns True when comparing two tennsors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have an original input value tensor `patches` to my model

```
patches.shape
torch.Size([64, 1280, 10])  # batch: 64, number of patches: 1280, original pixel values of each patch: 10
```

My model predicts the pixel values of specific patches that are masked and the indices of masked patches are saved in `masked_indices` with the shape of `torch.Size([64, 896])` means 896 patches out of 1280 are predicted by the model.

I wanna replace the original pixels values of those 896 patches with the new predicted values by the model (`pred_pixel_values, shape: torch.Size([64, 896, 10])`). I did the following

```
# for indexing purposes
batch_range = torch.arange(batch, device=device)[:, None]

pa = patches
pa[batch_range, masked_indices, :]= pred_pixel_values
pa.shape
torch.Size([64, 1280, 10])
```

I wanted to compare if the values are replaced or not:

```
torch.equal(pa,patches)
```

but it returns True. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: After doing `pa = patches`, you don't have two tensors, you have a single tensor with two names that refer to it.  They're guaranteed to compare as equal, because they're the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `deepcopy` here:

```
from copy import deepcopy
pa = deepcopy(patches)
```

As mentioned by [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper), when you do `pa = patches`, they basically refer to the same tensor with two different names or in other words `pa` is an [alias](https://www.codesansar.com/python-programming/aliasing.htm) of `patches`. As a result, whatever changes you make to either of them, automatically applies to the other one.

Answer (score 1):

By running `pa = patches`, you are just creating a reference to the same object in memory.

Instead, create a new tensor using `tensor.clone()`:

`pa = patches.clone()`

`clone` should be used in favor of `copy` or `deepcopy` for tensors, as it is more memory efficient and retains the computational graph.